# Add same document to same library on every site?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

Assuming I have 100 Sites in a collection, and a document library named "Phones" on every site, how can I use PowerShell to add the same document from my PC to every one of those libraries named "Phones" on each site?

I've seen a lot of different examples for adding a document to a single library but I'm not positive how to expand on that.

SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd put the document in one place, and then add a link to the document from each library.  That way, when the document changes, you only have to change it in one place.

That said, you should be able to wrap the "add" function in an iterator that cycles through all the sites in your site collection.